# client server video streaming without any plugin

Tags: javascript, asp.net, websocket

i have an Asp.Net application hat have client server video streaming functionality.
Two login credentials ,one is teacher and other one is student.when teacher select a video and students name and click on start button, that corresponding video will play in each selected students screen, and also when it stop it should be close from all corresponding students as well.

this functionality implemented using vlc plugin but now chrome not support vlc plugin,so i am trying using websocket.Is this is correct method ?? or any other better solution ??please let know soon....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can stream video using any third party javascript player plugin but you have mentioned "without plugin" so you can use inbuilt HTML5 video player, and you can connect student to the teacher using Websockets and thus you can stop video streaming whenever you want(By stoping the video upon websocket response, or removing the player itself if you want).

I think you can use WebRTC if it fits in your case
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/broadcast/

Comment: Thanks for your kind response